# The value of shallow file comparation

Tags: python, file, compare

In python's filecmp.py, there's the cmp function

```
def cmp(f1, f2, shallow=1):
    s1 = _sig(os.stat(f1))
    s2 = _sig(os.stat(f2))
    if s1[0] != stat.S_IFREG or s2[0] != stat.S_IFREG:
        return False
    if shallow and s1 == s2:
        return True
    if s1[1] != s2[1]:
        return False
    #content compare
    ......
```

So, when shallow is true, this function only compares the two files' *name, mtime (modification time) and file mode*.
Well, to me, if the files are actually one file, these are surely the same. If they are not one file, then I think there's no way the modification time will be the same.

Then, IMHO  the only usage of the function when shallow = 1  would be check if the two files we compare are actually one file~..  And I'm sure my guess is wrong, python wouldn't have such nonsense in its lib..

Please someone tell me in what condition the filecmp.cmp(f1, f2,  shallow=1) would be useful?

Answer (score 0):

You're misreading it. If `shallow` is on and the files' `os.stat()` signatures are different, the function does not return `False`. Instead, the function continues on to further checks.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Are there any chances the signature will be the same if two files are compared? I really don't think so.

Comment: @RobertBean: mtime isn't very precise, and you can set it to whatever you want with `os.utime` anyway. It's pretty easy to get two files with the same mtime.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I still saw no need for the existence of a 'shallow comparison'. Its difference from a common comparison would be, 'shallow comparison' regard 'mode size mtime' equality as equality. Such usage seems a little nonsense to me.. When comparing two files, we always want to compare their content, isn't it?